# How to check if SpeechRecognizer is currently running?

Tags: android, service, recognizer-intent

I am trying to track state of `SpeechRecognizer`, like that:

```
private SpeechRecognizer mInternalSpeechRecognizer;
private boolean mIsRecording;

public void startRecording(Intent intent) {
 mIsRecording = true;
 // ...
 mInternalSpeechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
}
```

Problem with that approach is keeping `mIsRecording` flag up to date is tough, e.g. if there's `ERROR_NO_MATCH` error should it be set to `false` or not?
I am under impression some devices stop recording then and others no.

I don't see any method like `SpeechRecognizer.isRecording(context)`, so I am wondering if there's way to query through running services.

Answer (score -2):

One solution to handle end or error cases is to set a `RecognitionListener` to your `SpeechRecognizer` instance. You must doing it **before** calling `startListening()`!

Example:

```
mInternalSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {

    // Other methods implementation

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        // Handle end of speech recognition
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        // Handle end of speech recognition and error
    }

    // Other methods implementation 
});
```

In your case, you can make your class containing the `mIsRecording` attribute implement `RecognitionListener` interface. Then, you just have to override these two methods with the following instruction:

```
mIsRecording = false;
```

**Furthermore**, your `mIsRecording = true` instruction is in the wrong place. you should do it in the `onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)` method definition, otherwise, speech recognition may never start while this value is true.

Finally, in the class managing it, juste create methods like:

```
// Other RecognitionListener's methods implementation

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    mIsRecording = false;
}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {
    mIsRecording = false;
    // Print error
}

@Override
void onReadyForSpeech (Bundle params) {
    mIsRecording = true;
}

public void startRecording(Intent intent) {
    // ...
    mInternalSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);
    mInternalSpeechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
}

public boolean recordingIsRunning() {
    return mIsRecording;
}
```

Be careful about thread safety for recordingIsRunning calls, and all will be ok :)

Comment: as I mentioned in a question, if `onError` is getting executed it does *not* mean device stopped recording audio. If it's ERROR_NO_MATCH sometimes it stops recording, sometimes not.

Comment: And what if you call `stopListening()` in case of `ERROR_NO_MATCH`?

Comment: But I don't want to stop recording if device wants to continue.

Comment: I understand but if an error is notified, will the recording give a result? If not, you should abort it as soon as the error is notified to prepare for a new recording instance.

Comment: I dont know, as it requires checking on large number of devices. Your answer is almost the same what I am doing currently. I was looking for a different approach, e.g. querying through running services to find out if one of them is launched by SpeechRecognizer.